# Find *installed* Python module(s?) providing the imported functionality

Tags: python-2.7, pip

Given a bunch of Python files -- which can be standalone scripts or modules -- that run correctly on a machine, how can I find out the *minimal* set of Python modules I need to install on a clean machine?

Basically I would like to compose a minimal `requirements.txt` or `install_requires` (for `setup.py`).

E.g. if I have these imports:

```
import re
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import json
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import time
import docx
```

`re` and `time` are packages that come with Python, so nothing else is required.
`django`, `sklearn`, and `numpy` could be fairly easily deduced since there is a matching package in `pip freeze`.
`json` and `docx` are a problem ... for example, I have both `anyjson` and `jsonschema` installed and `python-docx` and `docx`.

Comment: `json` is a standard library. `anyjson` and `jsonschema` are different imports.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's not my point. The question is in general. Given some code I'd like to know what packages need to be installed.